# Unable to use sc.textfile for amazon s3 with V4 authentication

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to read/write  a file from amazon s3 from a ec2 cluster using spark-shell. I have set the access key and secret key. But I am getting the same error everytime. The problem is only with region that only support V4 authentication.

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 699BD72FAC289B47, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request
```

I tried to set the endpoint also as most of the answer suggest. But still getting the same error.